# Payload size when upserting via SODA.NET API

Tags: socrata, soda

I am using the SODA.NET library to update a very large dataset. I've found the larger the payload, thus less chatty, is more performant. I'm currently sending 1000 records at a time.

What is the recommended upper limit to the payload size for an upsert call? Are there any hidden gotchas to be aware of as I increase the size?

Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to ping the Santa Monica team who created this library and maintains it on GitHub. Not sure if they check this site often and likely will have some advice. https://github.com/CityofSantaMonica/SODA.NET

Comment: I'm more interested in what Socrata's endpoint supports. The SODA.NET API wrapper looks to be performing well.

Answer (score 1):

With SODA 2 endpoints, you can throw all of your data at it (that's the default with the R-based libraries, for instance). Socrata will ingest at its own pace. Performance will depend a lot on network performance and number of columns.

Older SODA 1 endpoints capped around 50k.